# Draw text into elliptical shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am jumping right into it.

I am drawing a speech bubble with a `UIBezierPath`, the bubble is fine and works as I would expect. The problem is how do I add text to the speech bubble so it would stay inside the `UIBezierPath`. I have zero experience with drawing text, and I'm having a hard time coming up with possible solutions.

I have tried to fit a textview inside the bubble, but the solution did not work very well, and I would like to use more of the speech bubble. With the textview I can only use the rectangle shape, i would like to fill the bubble from top down, and use the complete width in the middle.

Any help and suggestions would be much appriciated.

[image]

Comment: If you know it's an ellipse and how big the text you're drawing will be, then there are definitely equations that will let you do what you want. (x^2)/a^2 + (y^2)/b^2 = 1 can easily be adapted to test if a point is inside of the ellipse. Personally, I don't know a way to do this without at least a moderate amount of math. You might want to head over to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi Dustin, thanks for the information. i will take a look at math.stackexchange.com and see if i come up with anything.

Comment: @MortenHN I am looking for some help with the speech bubble part. Care to share how you got it working? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i finally figured out how to draw/render text on a bezierpath, it can be done by taking the CGPath, and using core text. Ive did this method.

```
-(void)drawText:(NSString *)text {
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(myContext, 0.0f, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(myContext, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attString); // 7-2
    CTFrameRef theFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [attString length]), path, NULL); // 8-2

    CTFrameDraw(theFrame, myContext); // 11-2
    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
}
```

I followered this tutorial, witch is excelent. http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/core-text

now i only need to figure out how to calculate the size of the bezierpath to contain all the text, and figure out how to move the bezierpath and the core text together, they run on different coordinate system and is giving me all kind of problems. So if anybody has experience with this i am all ears!

Best Regards
Morten

Comment: The tutorial you cited is outstanding.  Not only does it provide the technical content, it is readable ;) with proper grammar, spelling, etc.